# Bug in Libdisasm?

Tags: c, enums, disassembly

I was doing some disassembly with the Libdisasm ( version .23 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/bastard/files/libdisasm/0.23/) when I came across a small bug. When I print the `enum x86_insn_type` from the `x86_insn_t` struct  (following http://bastard.sourceforge.net/libdisasm.html), I see that all floating point instructions seem to have the same type (all other instructions are fine) (as you can see below when I print the instruction)

```
Instruction type a000, fld  [ebp-0x10] 
Instruction type a000, fld  [0x8048588] 
Instruction type a000, fmulp st(1), st(0) 
Instruction type a000, fstp [ebp-0x10]
```

Here is a small part of the `enum x86_insn_type`,

```
 /* insn_fpu */
        insn_fmov = 0xA001,
        insn_fmovcc = 0xA002,
        insn_fneg = 0xA003,
        insn_fabs = 0xA004,
        insn_fadd = 0xA005,
        insn_fsub = 0xA006,
        insn_fmul = 0xA007,
        insn_fdiv = 0xA008,
```

Is this a bug in the libdisasm library (since it is pretty old and has not been updated for a pretty long time), OR am I doing something wrong?

Code used.

```
    x86_insn_t insn;
    char buf[MAX_INSN_SIZE];
    char line_to_print[LINE_SIZE];
    int size;
    int to_return;

    x86_init(opt_none, NULL, NULL);

    //Here I read one Instruction into buf and then call x86_disasm

    size = x86_disasm((unsigned char*)buf, MAX_INSN_SIZE, 0, 0, insn);
    if(size)
    {
        x86_format_insn(&insn, line_to_print, LINE_SIZE, intel_syntax);
        printf("Instruction type %x, %s \n", insn.type, line_to_print);
    }
    x86_cleanup();
```

Comment: Do you pass any options to the library?

Comment: During `x86_init` or `x86_disasm`?

Comment: Maybe you could show the code you use to access library?

Comment: I have posted the code.